# Insert into mongo by skipping duplicates along two indices

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb collection which has the following data (inserted using `insert_many`)

```
[
    {"attr_name": "a", "values": [
        {"value": "1", "embedding": [1,2,3]},
        {"value": "2", "embedding": [2,3,4]},
        {"value": "3", "embedding": [3,4,5]},
    ]},
    {"attr_name": "b", "values": [
        {"value": "1", "embedding": [1,2,3]},
        {"value": "4", "embedding": [4,5,6]},
    ]},
    {"attr_name": "c", "values": [
        {"value": "6", "embedding": [6,7,8]},
        {"value": "7", "embedding": [7,8,9]},
    ]},
]
```

I want duplicates to be avoided on the `attr_name` and `value`. This is enforced by

```
collection.create_index(["attr_name", "value"], unique=True)
```

What I want is, when new data is inserted, if there's a matching index for `attr_name`, it should append to the `values`. But now, if there's a matching `attr_name`, it omits the entire entry.

For example:
I have this:

```
[
    {"attr_name": "a", "values": [
        {"value": "1", "embedding": [1,2,3]},
        {"value": "2", "embedding": [2,3,4]},
    ]},
    {"attr_name": "b", "values": [
        {"value": "1", "embedding": [1,2,3]},
        {"value": "4", "embedding": [4,5,6]},
    ]},
]
```

I'm inserting this:

```
[
    {"attr_name": "a", "values": [
        {"value": "1", "embedding": [1,2,3]},
        {"value": "5", "embedding": [5,6,7]},
        {"value": "6", "embedding": [6,7,8]},
    ]},
    {"attr_name": "c", "values": [
        {"value": "6", "embedding": [6,7,8]},
        {"value": "7", "embedding": [7,8,9]},
    ]},
]
```

I want this to be the final state:

```
[
    {"attr_name": "a", "values": [
        {"value": "1", "embedding": [1,2,3]},
        {"value": "2", "embedding": [2,3,4]},    # <---- appended
        {"value": "5", "embedding": [5,6,7]},
        {"value": "6", "embedding": [6,7,8]},
    ]},
    {"attr_name": "b", "values": [
        {"value": "1", "embedding": [1,2,3]},
        {"value": "4", "embedding": [4,5,6]},
    ]},
    {"attr_name": "c", "values": [
        {"value": "6", "embedding": [6,7,8]},
        {"value": "7", "embedding": [7,8,9]},
    ]},
]
```

Comment: I don't think `collection.create_index(["attr_name", "value"], unique=True)` is doing what you want.  `"value"` is not at the top level within the document.  Did you want `collection.create_index(["attr_name", "values"], unique=True)`?  ... or maybe `collection.create_index(["attr_name", "values.value"], unique=True)`

Comment: ... although, I'm not sure there is a [multikey index modifier](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/#std-label-unique-separate-documents) that will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to issue individual [`update_one`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) commands with `upsert=True`.

Perhaps something like:

```python
my_updates = [
    {"attr_name": "a", "values": [
        {"value": "1", "embedding": [1,2,3]},
        {"value": "5", "embedding": [5,6,7]},
        {"value": "6", "embedding": [6,7,8]},
    ]},
    {"attr_name": "c", "values": [
        {"value": "6", "embedding": [6,7,8]},
        {"value": "7", "embedding": [7,8,9]},
    ]},
]

for update in my_updates:
    update_result = collection.update_one(
        filter={"attr_name": update["attr_name"]},
        update={"$addToSet": {"values": {"$each": update["values"]}}},
        upsert=True
    )
```

N.B.: You may want to inspect the values of [`update_result` properties](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.UpdateResult).